# unittest - Check the result of the previous test

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have some tests on my test suit and I want to check the result of the last test. What is the cleanest way to do it? It follows an example:

```
def test_01_first(self):
    if condition:
       assert False

def test_02_second(self):
    if first_test_has_failed:
       do_something...
```

I was thinking something like a class attribute (cls.test_failed = 1) but it doesn't seem elegant to me.

Answer (score 2):

Tests should be written such that they can be run in any order.  It took me a while to accept that, but testing became much easier when I did.

The best thing to do is have different Test classes for different areas of functionality so you can narrow down the running tests if you are experiencing many failures.

For example, one of my test suites has the following classes:

```
class TestPathBasics(TestCase):
    ...

class TestPathStringMethods(TestCase):
    ...

class TestPathFileOperations(TestCase):
    ...
```

Then from the command line I can run:

```
python -m antipathy.test TestPathBasics
```

to run a single group of tests, or even

```
python -m antipathy.test TestPathBasics.test_addition
```

to run a single test.

To actually answer your question: I would use a class attribute, possible along with a decorator, if I really, truly, absolutely had to run them in a certain order and needed to know something about the last test.